# Serverless Framework AWS 403 Forbidden Error with Domain Only

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework, serverless-plugins

I am working on a serverless setup for a project and ran into a strange error.  This was working fine before I had to delete my old certificates and make a new one.

In short, I am following the tutorial series at serverless-stack.com for reference, and when running the `apig-test` command I get the following error.

```
{ status: 403,
  statusText: 'Forbidden',
  data: { message: 'Forbidden' } }
```

This screams to me policy error.  So I went to check my policy to make sure it allows execution for the AuthRole and indeed it does.  I verified this in IAM section under Roles and looked my services Auth_Role that I created when I set up Cognito.

I don't want to give information overload here, but if anyone has any ideas for where to look next I would be much appreciative and I'll give any details you want to see here.

**One thing I want to note is that if I run the apig-test command with the direct URL to the Lambda function instead of my domain it works perfectly fine.**

This proves that nothing is wrong with my code but more a policy setting regarding how I setup the domain.

I ran sls create_domain accordingly and I see the entries in the Route53 & API Gateway and they have finished their 40 minutes many hours ago.  I insured its using correct certificate since I wiped out the other one.

**My custom domains have worked in the past** thanks to a plugin I found and this tutorial here (https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-api-gateway-domain/), **its only recently that it stopped working when I realized I needed to add some more domains to my SSL cert.**

So I assume the policy error is somewhere around this but not sure where to look?

Comment: 1. Do you have an authorizer in your api gateway setup? 2. Is the route you're trying to access visible in the api gateway resources?

Comment: For #2, In custom domains in API Gateway I do see the names and they finished their provisioning a while back.  The cname records are set accordingly also in Route53 to the target domain name specified.

Comment: I'm not sure what an authorizer is in the API gateway setup? how do I check that part?

Comment: Oh and yes under the API's I see all my routes, they definitely work because with the long super long domain name by default they give you, it works if I use that domain name with the command, it just doesn't work with my custom domains anymore for some reason.

Comment: In my case, I just had to deploy again and it worked.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok I found the answer.  In the API Gateway under custom domains there is a section called **Base Path Mappings** This MUST be set to one of your functions with the default path of / (or just enter nothing for the path) and then the destination to your lambda service.  This seemed to make it work for me.